# Ionic 4: How to overwrite style in Shadow elements that are not controlled by css variables?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I have to style a small app built with Ionic 4

The HTML is:

```
<div class="searchbar-wrapper">
  <ion-searchbar></ion-searchbar>
</div>
<div class="content-wrapper" #scrollingBlock>
  Content
</div>
```

I need to get rid of the shadow that Ionic by default adds to lots of its elements. I can see in Chrome devtools the searchbar like this:

```
    .searchbar-input.sc-ion-searchbar-md {

       ...
       -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
       box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    }
```

In theory I just need to set the **box-shadow** and the **webkit-box-shadow** equal to none. 
However, I can not even overwrite the box-shadow because it is in a Shadow element and there is not variable that control the shadow. Something like --box-shadow.

**The question:**

How could I “kill” styles coming from Ionic that are not govern by a variable and are in shadow-elements?

Comment: Rafael,  please add a simple working code so that you can get better help

Comment: @AlanM: Unfortunately Ionic add its own "magic" and therefore there is not more code than those few lines.

Comment: I have added the code there https://codepen.io/alanmehio/pen/VwYvaga?editors=1111  in case you want to put some comments and add more details

Comment: Hey Rafael, your problem is solvable but ideally please describe what are you trying to achieve? you just want to add box-shadow to input within searchbar element?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko, I want exactly the opposite. to eliminate the box-shadow of the searchbar that comes by default from Ionic

Comment: ok got it, i updated my answer, see if setting it to none helps

Answer (score 1):

[ion-searchbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar) as some other elements expose [a method to access underlying "input" element - getInputElement](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar#methods). That should allow you to add styles if needed. Below is how you can do that with Ionic 4.11.5:

Template remains the same, but in ts file you could do:

```
import { IonSearchbar } from '@ionic/angular';
///
export class MySearchPage {

    @ViewChild(IonSearchbar, { static: false }) searchbar: IonSearchbar;
    ///
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.searchbar.getInputElement().then((searchbarInputElement)=>{
      searchbarInputElement.style.boxShadow = "none";
        // in case you need to style its parent as well:
        //searchbarInputElement.parentElement.style.boxShadow = "none";
    })
  };

}
```

Let me know if this helps.