# Cancel box shadow in ion searchbar

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to hide the original box-shadow that has the element ion-searchbar but I can't hide it or delete it. I tried the next thing:

html:

```
<ion-searchbar placeholder = "Buscar" class = "nav_searchbar" spellcheck = "true" 
      animated = "true" autocomplete = "true" autocorrect = "true" [(ngModel)] = "busqueda" (input) = "setFilterData($event)"
      class = "hiddenBtnContainer">

        <ion-button class = "hiddenBtn" size = "small" (click) = "makeADeeperSearch()" focusable></ion-button>

</ion-searchbar>
```

css:

```
.nav_searchbar{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff !important;
    width: 80%;
    box-shadow: none;
    --box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}

.searchbar-input.sc-ion-searchbar-md{

    box-shadow: none;
    --box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;

}
```

but with these styles, the ion-searchbar element still has the box-shadow... a bit annoying.

ion-searchbar with the styles applied:

[image]

As you see, the searchbar has a little box shadow.

Devtools screenshot:

[image]

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Take in account that the div element with the class searchbar-input sc-ion-searchbar-md and all below that div (ion-icon and button) is auto generated by ionic (because a searchbar has the searchbutton and his respective icon).

Other important thing is that i have testing disabling the box-shadow of that specific element selected on devtools and works, so that's the problem, but still i'm not able to disable the box-shadow with the css properties that i have put (only works if i disable them directly in devtools), is like these css properties that i'm putting are being ignored.

Comment: Is there more specific CSS applying to the search bar? We can't really tell with what you've posted if that's happening.

Comment: No there isn't that are the unique styles that i'm aplying to the searchbar. other thing is that the searchbar is contained by a header (ion-header), this ion-header has a red color, but that's all.

Comment: use !important to override css properties. Ex :   `box-shadow: none !important;`

Comment: Added !important rule, but still not working.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of Dev tools (F12) on that element? Really can't tell why without a working code snippet  .

Comment: sure! i'm going to edit the question.

Comment: Hey!, found a solution, but i don't know how to mark this question as 'this question already has a solution here', so this is the link that helped me to solve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215542/ionic-4-how-to-overwrite-style-in-shadow-elements-that-are-not-controlled-by-cs?rq=1

Comment: I have marked it as Duplicate as per the comment above [Ionic 4: How to overwrite style in Shadow elements that are not controlled by css variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59215542/ionic-4-how-to-overwrite-style-in-shadow-elements-that-are-not-controlled-by-cs)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 `class` attributes on `<ion-searchbar>`:

`<ion-searchbar placeholder = "Buscar" class = "nav_searchbar" ... class = "hiddenBtnContainer">`

So the first one will be likely ignored. Try using `class` attribute properly:

`<ion-searchbar placeholder="Buscar" class="nav_searchbar hiddenBtnContainer" spellcheck="true" animated="true" autocomplete="true" autocorrect="true" [(ngModel)]="busqueda" (input)="setFilterData($event)">...`

Comment: Still not working, but other properties are now shown.